# Change ../Symfony/web/app.php to proper URL in Symfony 2

Tags: url, symfony

I need to route my url from ../Sym
fony/web/app.php/.. to my domain name such as www.example.com. Do any one you has a proper solution apart from using mod rewrite

Comment: use [virtual hosting](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts).